# css: body color not extending all the way down the page

Tags: html, css

I'm specifying a teal background color for the body of a page:

```
<body style="background-color: #0197B1">
```

This overrides a style sheet, and sure enough the teal appears, but not all the way down the page (both in Firefox and Chrome)

I add the following at the bottom:

```
 <br style="clear:both" />
  some text
 </body>
```

to attempt to resolve things and also debug what is occurring with the inline element at the bottom.  It appears (Chrome developer tool) that the body does not go all the way down the page. Hmm ... why does this happen, what's the fix?

Page can be viewed at: http://www.momentumnow.co/testimonials

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove the `height: 100%;` property on the body (it's set in the CSS) and the background will fill the entire page. Also, as a friendly note, you shouldn't be using tables to design websites. It's very poor practice - what you want to do is easily achievable without tables.

Comment: What does this "height: 100%" property do ... why does it have this effect?   Someone else set it in the style sheet, so I'm hesitant to change it.

Comment: @Ray, read my answer. "height: 100%" does exactly what you think it should - it makes the background 100% as tall as it thinks the page is. The issue is that your page has no idea whats going on.

Comment: It sets the height of the body element to the height of the *browser window*, not the document. This means that if the document extends past the window (i.e., if there's a vertical scrollbar), the styles only show on the part of the web page before you scroll down.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `html {background-color:#ffffff;}` and you should be done.

Answer (score 2):

When you float an element you are removing it from the document's flow. The page loses a sense of where and how large the element is.

You page is a series of nested tables with floated elements inside. The only thing providing actual vertical structure is the tables themselves. Your background is ended where the tables run out.

To recode this page would be easy for someone who was familiar with Standards-based, semantic markup. I would suggest learning those methods. In the meantime, @Christian Varga's solution will get you off for the time being.

Comment: Thanks -- I grabbed this page from someone else and wanted to quickly change the contents.  Indeed it is ugly.   Do you know how / why that height attribute messes things up?

Comment: @Ray the page thinks its only half the height it displays as because all of your elements with content are removed from the flow.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to recode this page.  Did you see Rodney's comment above on the 100% height?

Comment: Rodney is incorrect - percentage heights are based on the parent bounding box: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/height

Answer (score 1):

I check Firefox only,

```
line 4: html{background-color:#ffffff; height:100% }
```

Just remove `body`

or

```
line 4: html,body{background-color:#0197B1; height:100% }
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure what affect it will have on other developer who is using this style sheet.   I like your first solution better, specifying the teal background color both on html and body, which seemed to work.  Not clear what this height 100% means.  Can you clarify?